# Android FCM: FCM display(notification) message loggin when app is in background

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I am trying to implemenent some kind of logging for incoming message from FCM. We are using FCM **display(notification) messages** type. I am trying to find way to log incomming notification when application is in **background**. I am aware of that if I would be using FCM **Data message** type I can simple receive notificaiton in `onMessageReceived` callback from `FirebaseMessagingService` but unfortunately that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works in background if the fcm payload formed with data message. the notification message will just show message in system tray [app has no access of that message].

Comment: So there's no way to implement some kind of middleware between receving a showing notificaion? For example iOS can use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension ?